# Class Not Found Exception after cleaning project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, project, classnotfoundexception

I am currently working on a Java project in Eclipse that includes 44 java files and 1 SQL file.  After working on it for several hours today, I noticed that nothing I was doing affected the program when I ran it (I could delete all the code in the main class and it still ran fine).  I checked the class files and noticed they had not been modified for several days (since the last time I worked on it).  After doing some reading online, I took the advice to perform Project->Clean.  However, after doing that, I can no longer compile the project.  When I run the main class I simple get this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sprint1/Main2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sprint1.Main2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have checked the build path and from what I can tell everything seems correct.  I have also toggled Project->Build Automatically on and off to no avail.  The only thing I can think of to do now is create a new project and copy all the code to it, but I am using various obscure jars and SWT (which doesn't transfer well, if at all, in my experience).  Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure there are no build errors in any of your classes? If there are errors, eclipse would could run the previous error free version (according to some settings you provide). Build errors can also lead to the class files not being generated after a project clean.

Comment: Actually, Eclipse tells me that errors exist in the project when I click run, but it doesn't display any red marks in any of the files.  I tried saving all the files; nothing changed.

Comment: Is the problems window showing? If not click the Menu 'Window->Show View->Problems'. You can find build errors in that view.

Comment: I just selected all the problems in the problem window and deleted them, and that seems to have solved it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Check if exists any error in your project. Not just the compilation errors. Click on project and check the "Problems" view in Eclipse.

I think it happens usually when there is any JAR file missing in the project. Even if you don't use it.

Select Project in the Eclipse -> right button -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab

And check any red mark in the JAR files. Remove it of your Eclipse Project or fix the path (select JAR and click Edit button).